# UTF-8 Trouble y JQuery Response

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, character-encoding

I have an JSP/Servlet based aplication and their servlets have configured the response like that:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

The Servlets are called using JQuery Ajax, but when the response is back it does not Showing the special characters it has.

The JSP page where the response is put also has the CharSet setted.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false"%>
```

I dont know what to do.

Tracing results in the Tomcat Console i can see the special chars.

Comment: if i try, into the server i saw the same. So i dont know if problem begins at Server side or is just caused in client side